# Javascript contact form validation code

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, form, twig

I'm a UI / UX Designer trying to sharpen my JS skills.  I wanted someone else to check this code snippet and maybe have a Pro tip to improve or shorten it.

Javascript:

```
var formContainer = $('.contact-form-container');
var formError = $('.form-error');
var tosLabel = $('.tos-label');
var tosCheckbox = $('.tos-checkbox');

function checkBoxValidation(tosLabel, tosCheckbox, formError) {
    if (!tosCheckbox.is(':checked')) {
        tosLabel.removeClass('tos-is-checked');
        formError.addClass('tos-error');
    } else if (tosCheckbox.is(':checked')) {
        tosLabel.addClass('tos-is-checked');
        formError.removeClass('tos-error');
    }
}

tosCheckbox.change(function() {
    checkBoxValidation(tosLabel, tosCheckbox, formError);
});

formContainer.submit(function () {
    checkBoxValidation(tosLabel, tosCheckbox, formError);
});
```

HTML:

```
    <form data-abide novalidate method="post" action="{{ path(route) }}" class="contact-form-container">
        {% if contact.error %}
            <div data-abide-error class="callout alert">
                <p class="alert-text"><i class="fi-alert size-24"></i>{{ contact.error }}</p>
            </div>
        {% elseif contact.success %}
            <div class="callout success">
                <p class="success-text"><i class="fi-check size-24"></i>{{ contact.success }}</p>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="name-field">
            <label>Vor- und Nachname
                <input type="text" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" name="name" value="{{ contact.name }}">
                <small class="form-error">Vor- und Nachname angeben.</small>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="email-field">
            <label>Ihre E-Mail Adresse
                <input type="email" required name="email" value="{{ contact.email }}">
                <small class="form-error">Ihre E-Mail Adresse ist nicht korrekt.</small>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="message-field">
            <label>Ihre Nachricht
                <textarea placeholder="Schreiben Sie eine Nachricht" name="message" required>{{ contact.message }}</textarea>
                <small class="form-error">Ihre Nachricht angeben.</small>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="tos-field">
            <label for="checkbox1" class="tos-label">
                <input id="checkbox1" class="tos-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="privacy" {{ contact.privacy?'checked' }} required>
                Ich akzeptiere die Bestimmungen für den <a href="{{ path('tos') }}" class="tos-link">Datenschutz</a>.
            </label>
                <span class="form-error">Akzeptieren Sie die Bestimmungen zum Datenschutz.</span>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Senden">
    </form>
```

Comment: So all `'.tos-checkbox'` in that form have to be checked to not give error? can you add also the forms HTML?

Comment: Yes the  `.tos-checkbox` (terms of service) checkbox must be checked to submit the form.

Comment: $('.tos-checkbox') gives u ALL elements which have t. class '.tos-checkbox' upon it. That's a set. NOT a single element. In your case the set has just one element. But if you would extend your form so that you have two or more checkboxes with the class 'tos-checkbox' then it would become true if ANY of the checkbox becomes checked. Not deep into jQuery but obviously t. element which has become changed is t. this-keyword within t. handler-function. I guess jQuery passes that. Play around with this: http://codepen.io/mizech/pen/qNKAba?editors=1010 Perhaps u should use a more specific selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion:

```
var tosCheckbox = $('.tos-checkbox');
var checkBoxValidation = (function(label, checkbox, errorDisplay) {
    var checked = checkbox.is(':checked');
    return function(e) {
        if (e.type == 'submit' && !checked) e.preventDefault();
        tosLabel.toggleClass('tos-is-checked', checked);
        formError.toggleClass('tos-error', !checked);
    }
})(tosLabel.closest('label'), tosCheckbox, formError.closest('label').find('.form-error'));

tosCheckbox.change(checkBoxValidation);
tosLabel.closest('form').submit(checkBoxValidation);
```

Baiscally I tried to make the code dependent/related to `tosCheckbox`, finding both label, error and form from that element. This avoids pointing to the wrong thing like `'.form-error'` which I see more than one in the page. This way only the one inside the `label` will receive the class.

DRYed also the event listener callbacks, the class add/remove and added a check to prevent the form submit event. Not sure you need this, but its a heads up in case you are not stoping the submit in case of error.

Hope it helps.